# sails js model 'array' type validation and multiple select

Tags: express, sails.js

I'm adding a type validation for my model, example:

```
selectList: {
      type: 'array'
  }
```

The selectList input comes from HTML Form's Multiple Select.

**Problem**
When user selects zero or one option only, in the case of zero, we get undefined/object type, in case of 1 selection we get 'string' type. Saving it to the selectList will fail.

What is the best solution to handle this issue?
**Any ideas?** using beforeValidation doesn't sound a good solution to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use beforeValidation?

```
beforeValidation: function(obj, cb) {
    if (typeof obj.field === "array") {
        cb(null, obj);
    }

    if (typeof obj.field === "string")
    {
        var temp = obj.field ;
        obj.field = new Array();
        obj.field [0] = temp;
    }
    cb(null, obj);
}
```

Comment: I have the reverse issue. I want my API to be able to accept an array of strings or a string, and if it's an array, it will concatenate (is a specific manner) the strings. I thought of setting the type in the model to 'string' and then using `beforeValidate` to do the concatenation, but the value passed into `beforeValidate` (e.g. `obj.field` in your example) has already been cast to a string. Am I missing something? Sails 0.10.0-rc5